# How to add /admin/people as a tab to a custom menu?

Tags: 8, routes, navigation

In a custom module (association), I ceated views that are accessible thru tabs:
[image]
The paths are defined in the views;

- Adhérents et personnes -> /association (this one is also defined as a
  menu item)
- Adhérents -> /association/members
- Personnes -> /association/persons

I'd like to add `/admin/people` as a fourth tab.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally and because of the side effect of the solution proposed by Mike Nolan (see [capture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmQCi.png) in my comment), I made it that way:

```
function association_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name) {

  $oCurrentUser = \Drupal::currentUser();
  switch ($route_name) {
    case 'view.association_members_and_persons.page_1':
    case 'view.association_members.page_1':
    case 'view.association_persons.page_1':
      if ($oCurrentUser->hasPermission('administer users')) {
        $data['tabs'][0]['association.people'] = [
          '#theme' => 'menu_local_task',
          '#link' => [
            'title' => t('Users'),
            'url' => Url::fromRoute('entity.user.collection'),
          ],
          '#weight' => 4,
        ];
      }
      break;
    default:
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a custom module (mymodule), create a mymodule.links.task.yml file, and add the following:

mymodule.admin_people:
  route_name: entity.user.collection
  base_route: route.of.your.custom.menu
  title: 'Tab text goes here'

Here's what each part does:

**mymodule.admin_people** Is the identifier of your menu tab item (the file being *.links.task.yml means its the menutab file)

**route_name**  is the route the tab points to, and **entity.user.collection** is the route that corresponds to /admin/people .

**base route** displays your tab on the specified route. To find the route for your view, download the Devel module, turn it on, and go to "Routes info" to get your route. Usually a view is of the format view.[view_machine_name].[view_display_id], i.e. view.myview.page_1 . Check the "advanced" section of your view's management page for the display ID.

**title** is the text that will go into the tab.

Comment: also note, *.links.action.yml specifies action links i.e. add buttons you tend to see of some admin pages, and *.links.menu.yml creates menu items. Each one uses slightly different YAML, so look at other modules for clues.

Comment: It works!
[capture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDqyV.png)
but when I go to `/admin/people`, I get my custom tabs miwed with standard Drupal tabs:
[capture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmQCi.png)
How to avoid this?

Comment: And, by the way, how can I get the weight of each tab?

Comment: For your own tabs, you can set a 'weight' property. For seeing other tabs, take a look at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-local-tasks , which explains how to set up derivers, among other interesting tricks.